# Nuget Restore is not creating lib directory for some packages

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, nuget, teamcity, .net-standard-2.0

**TL;DR**

While building on TeamCity, Nuget is restoring the DLL file of a .NET Standard 2.0 package into the root of the package rather than into its framework-specific lib folder.  This is resulting in Visual Studio being unable to find the assembly.

**More details:**

We have created a Nuget package targeting netstandard2.0 and published it.  We have a solution with a bunch of .NET Framework 4.6.1 projects, some of which depend on the aforementioned Nuget package (with valid entries in their respective packages.config files)

Unzipping the Nuget package, the contents are:

```
foo.nupkg
|- lib
|   |- netstandard2.0
|       |- foo.dll
|- package
|- _rels
|- foo.nuspec
```

Note that the dll is inside the netstandard2.0 directory.  Accordingly the reference and hint path to this dll in the csproj files looks like:

```
<Reference Include="foo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\foo.1.0.22\lib\netstandard2.0\foo.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

And indeed on my development machines, running VS2017 15.9.3 and Nuget 4.9.2, the package dll is restored exactly where it should be, inside the netstandard2.0 folder, whether I restore with VS or with nuget.exe.

However, when attempting to restore packages and build this solution in TeamCity, using the Nuget Installer (4.9.2) and Visual Studio 2017 runner types, the compilation fails because it cannot find the `foo` namespace.  Looking deeper at the logs, the ResolveAssemblyReference step of msbuild is warning that it cannot resolve foo.dll:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110, 5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "foo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors
        For SearchPath "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}".
        ...
        For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
        Considered "..\packages\foo.1.0.22\lib\netstandard2.0\foo.dll", but it didn't exist.
        For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
        ...
```

It cannot find the dll in the lib/netstandard2.0 directory.  I took a look at the packages directory post-restore and the foo subdirectory looks like this:

```
packages/foo
|- foo.dll
|- foo.pdb
|- foo.nupkg
|- foo.deps.json
```

There is no lib nor netstandard2.0 folder and the dll is in the root of the package.

Adding a build step that explicit creates the lib\netstandard2.0 folder before compilation fixes the issue but that's obviously not a maintainable solution.  I really need to understand what we're doing wrong here and why Nuget isn't restoring that dll to the lib folder.

And the mind-boggling thing is: other .NET Standard 2.0 dlls are restored into their package's lib/netstandard2.0 directories.  It's only the `foo` package that's not working correctly.

**Troubleshooting already attempted:**

Here are the troubleshooting steps I have tried but which have made no difference:

- Downgraded the Nuget version we are using in TeamCity to 3.2
- Included the `-NoCache` argument to Nuget
- Targeted the dependent projects at .NET Framework 4.7.2 (instead of 4.6.1)
- Used both `nuget restore` and `nuget install`

I have run out of both ideas and hair to pull out.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What is your restore resource when you restore from TeamCity? Have you manually  download the nuget package from the restore resource to check if that package is correct construction, if it have netstandard2.0 folder?